# Write lists to csv in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, csv

I have this list list of values:

Output of list_a:

```
list_a: [[[2.0, 4.0], [1.0, 2.0]], [[2.0, 4.0], [2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 1.0]], [[3.0, 6.0], [5.0, 5.0], [6.0, 4.0]], [[3.0, 6.0], [4.0, 7.0]], [[2.0, 4.0], [3.0, 6.0]]]
```

I want to export it to a csv file in a specific format so that every set of values occupies a cell in the following format:

```
 (2.0; 4.0) | (1.0; 2.0)
 (2.0; 4.0) | (2.0; 3.0) | (3.0; 1.0)
 ...
```

The "|" represents the separation of cells on the same row (not to be included in the csv file) and the format of the values in the cell should be parentheses and semicolon as such (X1; X2)

I tried the following but I get brackets and colons:

```
with open('outputdata.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    mywriter = csv.writer(outfile)

    for d in result:
        mywriter.writerow(d)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That's not how you define a list in Python.  Unless that's in a dictionary or something similar

Comment: To clarify, your `list_a` is not a multidimensional array but a list of lists.

Comment: This is the output of list_a from python, and yes I fixed the title

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to generate the output file without the writer:

```
SEP = ',' # Use any other separator here, if you want
with open('outputdata.csv', 'w') as outfile:
   for line in list_a:
      outfile.write(SEP.join(['({}; {})'.format(*pair) for pair in line]))
      outfile.write("\n")
```

Comment: The '|' represents going to another cell in the same row, it is not to be written int he csv file.

Comment: That's what you used in your example. You can use a comma or any other symbol instead.

Comment: I don't need a separator I need to move cells on the same row and not have the entire line in one cell.

Comment: All cells in a CSV file are separated with a separator (typically with a comma). That's how a cell is defined. If there are no separators, there are no cells. I suggest that you try rnning the code and then open the file in excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write the csv yourself, without any writer class:

```
with open('outputdata.csv', 'w') as f:
    for vector in list_a:
        len_ = len(vector)
        for i, point in enumerate(vector):
            f.write("({}; {})".format(*point))
            # avoid writing the last pipe
            if i != len_ - 1:
                f.write(" | ")
        f.write("\n")
```

Contents:

```
(2.0; 4.0) | (1.0; 2.0)
(2.0; 4.0) | (2.0; 3.0) | (3.0; 1.0)
(3.0; 6.0) | (5.0; 5.0) | (6.0; 4.0)
(3.0; 6.0) | (4.0; 7.0)
(2.0; 4.0) | (3.0; 6.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with open('outputdata.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    mywriter = csv.writer(outfile)
    for d in result:
        row = ' | '.join(['(%f; %f)' % (t[0], t[1]) for t in d])
        mywriter.writerow(d)
```

Each element of each row is an array of of two floats, right? So, we use a format string to convert `[2.0, 4.0]` to `"(2.0; 4.0)"`. We do this for every tuple in the row. Then, we just use python's `join()` function to put the characters `|` between them and link them all into one string, which we can write to the file.

Comment: I don't want to link them into one string not connect them via '|' I used that symbol to mark a new cell so that each pair (X1;X2) is in a single cell on the same row and then we switch rows